# Push data in array inside square brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var a = ['NYC', 'Boston', 'London', 'NYC', 'Boston', 'NYC', 'Sfo', 'Boston', 'Sfo', 'London', 'Edison', 'Sfo', 'NYC', 'charlotte', 'Edison', 'NYC', 'Manchester'];
a = a.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
    if (typeof acc[curr] == 'undefined') {
        acc[curr] = 1;
    } else {
        acc[curr] += 1;
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Step 1: variable a will look like this after the above code is executed
a = ['NYC':5,'London':2,'Boston':3,'Sfo':3,'Edison':2,'Manchester':1]

Step 2: push above array a inside the data sum as shown below

```
var datasum = [
    ['NYC', 5],
    ['London', 2],
    ['Boston', 3],
    ['Sfo', 3],
    ['Edison', 2]
    ['Manchester', 1]
];
```

How can i push variable "a" inside "Datasum" as shown above in Javascript? Any help much appreciated.

Note:- if you just want to push variable a in the above datasum variable, use datasum.push()

Comment: Do you mean, `datasum.push(a);`? Because that is a function.

Comment: what you want is to put an array inside another, or increment the counter in a pre-existent array. right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't exactly clear, but I gather that you want to generate `datasum` as shown from `a`. Just pushing `a` will not do that. You can do this, though:

```
var datasum = [];
for (var i in a) { datasum.push([i, a[i]]);
```

Note that this doesn't guarantee a particular order of the elements of `datasum`.

Comment: +1 Probably this is what OP is looking for and this makes sense.

Comment: +1, Also it would be good if you mention that we previously answered, I mean, `If you want to push th whole a...`.

Comment: @min2bro - I think my code does that. Each call to `push` has a single, two-element array as its argument. At the end, `datasum` will be an array of two-element arrays.

Comment: @min2bro - Your fiddle code isn't at all like what I suggested. You are assigning a new array to `datasum` each time through the `for` loop. Instead, you should just push a single array each time through.

Comment: @TedHopp I have achieved what I was looking for..Thanks for all your support I accepted ur answer too...

Comment: @SheikhHeera, added your suggestion too.